# Disable SpecialKeys

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Afternoon

I am looking to disable special keys such as CTRL+Break, F11 etc.

The code below is in a macros which is my AutoExec - It doesn't debug but also doesn't seem to work at all:

Any help is appreciated

**Code:**

```
Dim prp As DAO.Property
Set db = CurrentDb()
Select Case X
    Case 1
    Set prp = db.CreateProperty("StartUpShowDBWindow", 1, 1)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Case 2
    Set prp = db.CreateProperty("AllowBreakIntoCode", 1, 1)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Case 3
    Set prp = db.CreateProperty("AllowSpecialKeys", 1, 1)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Case 4
    Set prp = db.CreateProperty("AllowToolbarChanges", 1, 1)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Case 5
    Set prp = db.CreateProperty("AllowFullMenus", 1, 1)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Case 6
    Set prp = db.CreateProperty("AllowBuiltInToolbars", 1, 1)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Case 7
    Set prp = db.CreateProperty("AllowByPassKey", 1, 1)
        db.Properties.Append prp
    Case Else
    'do nothing
```

Comment: Where is the variable `X` set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These properties are loaded before the AutoExec macro fires, and set for the *next* startup. You need to restart your database before they take effect.

Furthermore, they are boolean properties, which means: `db.CreateProperty("StartUpShowDBWindow", 1, False)`, not `db.CreateProperty("StartUpShowDBWindow", 1, 1)` if you want to disable certain functionality.

Comment: Also - you need some way of allowing you, as developer, in to the database, have you considered how you would achieve that once this code is run?

Comment: I suggest adding this to the answer as well: an error will occur if you Append a property that already exists, so you have to try setting its value and catch the error and create/append it if it does not exist.